# How to convert Slate JS hover menu to React Hooks?

Tags: react-hooks, slatejs

Slate JS provides an example of a pretty slick [hover menu based on a traditional Class component](https://www.slatejs.org/#/hovering-menu). My goal is to convert this for use with React Hooks. I think I'm 95% of the way there, but I'm hung up on how to pass certain props from the Editor component to the `updateMenu()` function, which is called by the lifecycle functions. Here are psuedo-ish code representations of the Class and Hook components:

Class

```
class EditorWithHoveringMenu extends Component {
  menuRef = React.createRef()
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.updateMenu();
  };
  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    this.updateMenu();
  };
  updateMenu = () => {
    const menu = this.menuRef.current;
    if (!menu) return;

    const { value: {fragment, selection } } = this.props; // the future problem
    ...do more stuff
  }
  renderEditor = (props, editor, next) => {
    const children = next();
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {children}
        <HoverMenu ref={this.menuRef} editor={editor} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Editor
        value={this.props.value}
        renderEditor={this.renderEditor}
      />
  }
}
```

Hooks

```
function Editor() {
  const menu = useRef(null);
  const { text, setText } = useContext(EditorContext); // editor state now derived from context

  // In practical terms, this effect should run whenever text is selected/highlighted or deselected.
  useEffect(() => {
    updateMenu(menu, ???);
  });

  const updateMenu = (menuRef, value) => {
    const menu = menuRef.current;
    if (!menu) return;
    const { fragment, selection } = value; // Not sure how to get at these without `this`
    ...do more stuff
  }
  const renderEditor = (props, editor, next) => {
    const children = next();
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {children}
        <HoverMenu ref={menu} editor={editor} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  return (
    <Editor
      value={Value.fromJSON(text)}
      renderEditor={renderEditor}
    />
  )
}
```

Essentially, I've redefined `updateMenu()` to not reference `this`, but whereas I can easily pass the menu ref, I do not understand how to access the editor's selected/highlighted text, which apparently was previously passed via props.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue through a bit of trial and error. Examining the original Class component example, the destructure `const { value: {fragment, selection } } = this.props;` is in reference to a [slate.js Value object](https://docs.slatejs.org/slate-core/value#properties).

Once I understood that, it was as simple as passing a Value-ified copy of `text` (from the `useContext` reference) as an argument to `updateMenu()`:

```
const { text, setText } = useContext(EditorContext);

// From this
useEffect(() => {
  updateMenu(menu, ???);
});

// To this
useEffect(() => {
  updateMenu(menu, Value.fromJSON(text));
});
```